# Add values to PHP array

Tags: php

When I print

```
foreach ($result_target AS $target) {
    $code_target = substr($target['code'], 4);
    if ($code_source === $code_target) {
        if ($source['quantity'] !== $target['quantity']) {
            print $source['quantity'] .' -> ' . $target['quantity']."<br /><br />";
            $match[] = array('code' => $source['code'], 'quantity' => $source['quantity'], 'targetid' => $target['id'], 'sourceid' => $source['id']);      
        }
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

I have this results: http://suszek.info/projekt1/ Like You see there is 50 values. When I print $match there is much more, duplicated value and I don't know why ?

```
$msg = '';
foreach ($match AS $entry) {
    $msg .= 'Change identified: Home_ID=' . $entry['sourceid'] . ' code: ' . $entry['code'] . ' quantity:' . $entry['quantity'] . PHP_EOL . '<br />';
    print $msg;
    /*  Perform DB updates using $entry['targetid'] and $entry['quantity'] */
}
```

I have this results: http://suszek.info/projekt1/index_1.php And all code:

```
 $match = array(); $new = array();

 foreach ($result_source AS $source) {

     $found = false;
     $code_source = substr($source['code'], 4);
     foreach ($result_target AS $target) {
         $code_target = substr($target['code'], 4);
         if ($code_source === $code_target) {
             if ($source['quantity'] !== $target['quantity']) {
                 print $source['quantity'] .' -> ' . $target['quantity']."<br /><br />";
                 $match[] = array('code' => $source['code'], 'quantity' => $source['quantity'], 'targetid' => $target['id'], 'sourceid' => $source['id']);      
             }
             $found = true;
             break;
         }
     }

     if (!$found) {
         $new[] = array('code' => $source['code'], 'quantity' => $source['quantity'], 'sourceid' => $source['id']);
     } } $msg = ''; foreach ($match AS $entry) {
     $msg .= 'Change identified: Home_ID=' . $entry['sourceid'] . ' code: ' . $entry['code'] . ' quantity:' . $entry['quantity'] . PHP_EOL
 . '<br />';
     print $msg;
     /*  Perform DB updates using $entry['targetid'] and $entry['quantity'] */ }

 foreach ($new AS $entry) {
     $msg .= 'New Entry: Home_ID=' . $entry['sourceid'] . ' code: ' . $entry['code'] . ' quantity:' . $entry['quantity'] . PHP_EOL . '<br
 />';
     #print $msg;
     /*  Perform DB inserts using $entry['code'] and $entry['quantity'] if this is desired behaviour */ }

 /*  Send email with $msg  */
```

Where is the problem ? Why $match give me different output then

```
print $source['quantity'] .' -> ' . $target['quantity']."<br /><br />";
```

Comment: you also have duplicates in your `suszek.info/projekt1/` ! 0 -> 8 for example

Comment: You have right. But there is much less value than in the second example.